# Stored Procedure with dynamic SQL returns wrong data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

For the fiscal year parameter I have 2010, 2011 and 2012 as an option but no matter what year I select the "submitted On" column still shows 2011 dates. I want for example if I select 2010, only data submitted on 2010 should show and likewise for all the years. Any help?

```
  set @sqlstr = '
  Select 
    [SchoolName] As [School Name],
    Status= CASE  WHEN PS.PrivateSchoolID = Ed.PrivateSchoolID THEN ''Submitted'' 
         ELSE ''Not Submitted''END,
    [Submitted By]= CASE WHEN PS.PrivateSchoolID = Ed.PrivateSchoolID 
             THEN [FirstName] + '' '' + [LastName] ELSE NULL END,
    [Submitted On]= CASE WHEN PS.PrivateSchoolID = Ed.PrivateSchoolID 
               THEN Convert( Varchar(10), Ed.CreatedDate, 101 ) ELSE NULL END
   From EnrollmentDateSchool Ed Right Outer Join 
    (select FP.FiscalYear, PrivateSchool.* from PrivateSchool
        INNER JOIN FiscalYearPrivateSchool FP 
                ON PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID = FP.PrivateSchoolID) PS 
          ON Ed.PrivateSchoolID = PS.PrivateSchoolID Left Outer Join 
    Finance.dbo.Person P ON Ed.CreatedBy = P.PersonID
  Where (FiscalYear = '+convert(varchar, @FiscalYear)+') AND (PS.IsActive = 1)' 


IF (@SchoolID != -1)
    set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND SchoolID ='+ convert(varchar, @SchoolID)

IF (@Status = -1)
    set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND (PS.PrivateSchoolID = PS.PrivateSchoolID' + ')'
ELSE IF (@Status = 1)
    set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND (PS.PrivateSchoolID = Ed.PrivateSchoolID' + ')'
ELSE 
    set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + 'AND (Ed.PrivateSchoolID is null' + ')'

    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + 'ORDER BY SchoolName'
 EXEC(@sqlstr)
 END
```

Comment: Can you show the output when you use `PRINT @sqlstr;` instead of `EXEC(@sqlstr)`?

Comment: Also, don't use `CONVERT(VARCHAR, ` without length. Why? https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 6):

There is no need at all for dynamic sql here.

```
SELECT
   ...
FROM ...
WHERE FiscalYear=@FiscalYear AND PS.IsActive=1
AND (@SchoolID = -1 OR SchoolID=@SchoolID)
AND ( (@Status = -1) 
      OR (@Status=1 AND PS.PrivateSchoolID = Ed.PrivateSchoolID) 
      OR (Ed.PrivateSchoolID is null) )
ORDER BY SchoolName
```

Comment: +1 I was about to post something very similar. Dynamic SQL just to build a `WHERE` clause makes baby Jesus cry.

Comment: I was also posting something similar. Spent too much time formatting the parts left out (...)